# Visiting the Site for N consecutive days

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

Would I earn that badge for all my accounts in different Stack Exchange websites if I visit any one of them each day?

Comment: Yes, badges are all per-site. There isn't any cross-site badge. (yet?)

Comment: @Shadow9 did you mean that the answer is a "no"?

Comment: The answer is "Yes". If you visit a site for N consecutive days, you'll get a badge. On each site where you do it.

Comment: The badge is per site and per site only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would earn that badge for all your accounts if you visit **all of them** each day. Or, if you visit only a couple of them (let's say Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange) every day, you'll get the badge on exactly those two sites.

Just visiting a *single* site on Monday, another one on Tuesday, etc. won't work. When it comes to badges, sites/accounts are (almost) completely unaware of each other; the exceptions are badges like [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) which form a bridge between a single Stack Exchange site and its own Meta site. This isn't explicitly mentioned in the FAQ or the Help Center, but [What are badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-are-badges) does say:

> Badges are little bits of digital flair that you earn for almost every kind of activity on *Meta Stack Exchange.*

(emphasis mine - it does *not* say 'activity on Stack Exchange'.)